# picocom: list all connected ports

Tags: serial-port, ttyusb

I have a bunch (20+) of serial ports connected to my linux machine. `ttyUSB0` through `ttyUSB27` as of now. I use `picocom` to connect/monitor these ports, but not all of them are connected.
If I want to connect `picocom` to a new port I have to either

- go through all the port numbers until I find the ones that are not connected yet
- or try to see what all I have connected in order to find the ones that are not.

This process is cumbersome with such a large number or ports.
Is there a way to get a list of the connected (or disconnected) ports from `picocom`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A one liner (edited):

```
ps | grep picocom | awk '{print $1}' | tr -s '\n' ',' | xargs lsof -p | grep ttyUSB
```

Searches through the running processes for `picocom` captures the PID and lists the open files, filtering them on the string `ttyUSB`.

The last column of output should show all your `/dev/ttyUSB` devices.

Comment: That's a great start. I can get the list I was looking for. But, `lsof` takes a comma separated list without spaces where `xargs` returns a list separated by spaces; so I had split your one liner in two parts.

Comment: Replacing the new line from the output with commas accommodates the input requirements, therefore, the following modification works: 
`ps | grep picocom | awk '{print $1}' | tr -s '\n' ',' | xargs lsof -p | grep ttyUSB` 
I can accept your answer if you update it.